# Why do I get this error while my code is still working?

Tags: php, angular, api

I get this error and I have no idea why do I get it, my code works but still, having an error means that something is not good. Could you please help me out?

[image]

HERE:

```
addDepartment (name:string, location:string):Observable<any> { return this.http.post(this.depCreate,{ "name": name, "location": location}, httpOptions); }
```

Database code here. I hope it will help you help me fix this:

```
function create(){

// query to insert record
$query = "INSERT INTO
            " . $this->table_name . "
  JSON.stringify({ "name": name, "location": location})";

          //  echo $query;

// prepare query

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
if (!$stmt)
  var_dump($this->conn->errorInfo());

// sanitize
$this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
$this->location=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->location));



// bind values
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
$stmt->bindParam(":location", $this->location);


// execute query
if($stmt->execute()){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do not create your own json. Create an array, then use json_encode. The error is because the javascript cannot parse the response from the server, so check the Network tab to see what the full response is

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l4in7g the response

Comment: You're echoing your query somewhere. Find out where, and remove it. It's probably in the `create` function.

Comment: I did it. the error is still there.

Comment: well your first error was because of the I FROM insert ;) if you post a valid JSON string the error should be gone

Comment: Check the response tab now. What does it say? If it looks like valid json, then what is the full error now?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l4iw9n

Comment: You're still echoing the query. Show your Database code. Just make sure to remove any credentials.

Comment: You can see the database code now

Comment: Whoops, sorry, meant the Department code, not Database.

Comment: You can see it now

Comment: This code does not match your error message. And `JSON.stringify` is not a mysql function, so that will fail completely.

Comment: It used to be like this:   (name,location)    values (
                :name,:location)"; 

And still did not work

Comment: Show your current Response with the correct query?

Comment: the same as before

Comment: Then you have that code somewhere else. It should not be echoing the query, so go through your code to find out where it is.

Comment: Oh, god, I managed to fix it. Thanks. Really appreciated.

Comment: How I can make your comment to be the one that fixed my issue?

Comment: Comments can't be marked as answers. Which comment fixed it?

Comment: Well, I looked for another echo of the query and I found it.

Comment: But it is strange that now I get an empty object created from time to time

Answer (score 0):

You have to send valid JSON. `json_encode` helps a lot

```
$message = ['message' => 'department was created.'];
echo json_encode($message);
```

The other way around:

Also you could use `$json = json_decode($string, true);`

to create an array from some POST vars you send with javascript.

Some code for you script (replace from : `// create the department` until end of script)

```
$message = $department->create()
    ? 'department was created.'
    : 'Unable to create department.';

echo json_encode(['message' => $message]);
```

Comment: Did not help it

Comment: can you post your javascript where you are calling this script as well?

Comment: My Angular: addDepartment (name:string, location:string):Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post(this.depCreate,{
            "name": name,
            "location": location},
            httpOptions);
    }

Comment: is your ->create() echoing stuff?

Comment: can you format that code and add it to your question?

Comment: it string that you get an SQL query in your response, this has to come from somewhere

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the body as a string. use `JSON.stringify({ "name": name, "location": location})` instead of `{ "name": name, "location": location}`.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: looks like there is a syntax error in DB query after using the values from the body of request (or something processed using request body).